# How to use push Storyboard Segue for the NavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard

I am new in iOS development. I created an App using Storyboard to navigate to different pages.

[image]

When I click on the Add BarButton in Customer page --> go to the Add Customer Page.(using `Modal` Storyboard Segue)

There, when I enter username and password and click on save button --> come back to Customer page.

And everything works fine.

The problem is I want to have `back button` in Add Customer page. I already know that I can use `Push` Storyboard Segue, but when I use it I face with an error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13cb022 0x155ccd6 0xeff1b 0xefa24 0x44bde6 0x4404d0 0x13cce99 0x1814e 0x256a0e 0x13cce99 0x1814e 0x180e6 0xbeade 0xbefa7 0xbe266 0x3d3c0 0x3d5e6 0x23dc4 0x17634 0x12b5ef5 0x139f195 0x1303ff2 0x13028da 0x1301d84 0x1301c9b 0x12b47d8 0x12b488a 0x15626 0x25ed 0x2555)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

CustomerViewController.h:

```
#import "AddCustomerViewController.h"
    @interface CustomerViewController : UITableViewController<AddCustomerViewControllerDelegate>
    {
        IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
        NSMutableArray *customers;
    }

    @property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
    @property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *customers;

    @end
```

This is the code I use in CustomerViewController.m:

```
self.customers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddCustomer"])
    {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        AddCustomerViewController *addCustomerViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        addCustomerViewController.delegate = self;
    }
}

-(void) addCustomerViewControllerDidSave: (AddCustomerViewController *) Controller newCustomer: (Customer *) customer
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion:NULL];
    [self.customers addObject:customer];
    [self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

AddCustomerViewController.h:

```
#import "Customer.h"

@class AddCustomerViewController;

@protocol AddCustomerViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) addCustomerViewControllerDidSave: (AddCustomerViewController *) Controller newCustomer: (Customer *) customer;

@end

@interface AddCustomerViewController : UITableViewController
{

}

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <AddCustomerViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *firstnameTxt;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *lastnameTxt;

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender;

@end
```

And AddCustomerViewController.m:

```
- (void)save:(id)sender 
{
    NSLog(@"Save");
    Customer *newCustomer = [[Customer alloc]init];
    newCustomer.firstname = self.firstnameTxt.text;
    newCustomer.lastname = self.lastnameTxt.text;
    [self.delegate addCustomerViewControllerDidSave:self newCustomer:newCustomer];

}
```

Can you help me how can I use `Push` Storyboard Segue (to have back button) ?

Comment: Yes, get rid of the second navigation controller. How are you segueing to the add customer view controller? What kind of segue? Is it a modal?

Comment: Yes it is Modal which works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, get rid of the second navigation controller like what everybody here are saying.

Then, in storyboard, connect the "+" button directly to Add Customer View Controller and set the segue as push.

Next, click on the navigation bar of Customer view controller, in the attributes inspector where you should have defined the title ("Customer") for this view, there should be a "Back Button" row. Type "Back" and you will get a Back button in Add Customer view controller.

In prepareForSegue,

```
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddCustomer"])
{    
    AddCustomerViewController *addCustomerViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    addCustomerViewController.delegate = self;
}
```

To close Add Customer View controller, use popViewControllerAnimated as follows:

```
-(void) addCustomerViewControllerDidSave: (AddCustomerViewController *) Controller newCustomer: (Customer *) customer
{
    [self.customers addObject:customer];
    [self.tableview reloadData];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my delay to reply. Yes your code is completely working.

Answer (score 3):

You only need one navigation controller. Try delete the second navigation controller and set the segue from your first table directly to your second one.

Edit:

I took a more careful look and I think you should use `popViewControllerAnimated` rather than `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated`. The latter is for modal, the former is for push.

Comment: I did that but I got an error also on that way. I will post the error for you.

Comment: is that for `popViewControllerAnimated`?

Comment: Thanks, But how can I use popViewControllerAnimated? I don't know where did I use dismissModalViewControllerAnimated!

Comment: First line in your `addCustomerViewControllerDidSave`. Sorry `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` is the same as `dismissViewControllerAnimated`.

Comment: This is the new error with popViewControllerAnimated : `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13cb022 0x155ccd6 0xeff1b 0xefa24 0x44bde6 0x4404d0 0x13cce99 0x1814e 0x256a0e 0x13cce99 0x1814e 0x180e6 0xbeade 0xbefa7 0xbe266 0x3d3c0 0x3d5e6 0x23dc4 0x17634 0x12b5ef5 0x139f195 0x1303ff2 0x13028da 0x1301d84 0x1301c9b 0x12b47d8 0x12b488a 0x15626 0x25bd 0x2525)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)`

Comment: I just used it like this: `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]`

Comment: are you still having two navigation controllers? Can you post updated code? What superclass do your two tableview controllers have?

Comment: I removed the second `navigationController`. I added all my code to the end of question. Still it doesn't work. the error is what I commented here.

Comment: I got where error happen : `if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddCustomer"])` the prblem is when I remove this line I can go to seccond page but by click on save button I don't come back to customer page.

Comment: Can you update your code for `CustomerViewController.m` too? You need to set the second tableview controller as your `destination`, as you've removed the second `navController`. You also need to change `dismissViewController` into `popViewController` since you are using push.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for my late reply. I found you answer useful and I appreciate for your help. @Rick codes solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't push a navigation controller.  I doubt you need the second one in that scenario, but sometimes that usage can come in handy.

However, you need to set the style to Modal (or Custom - and provide your own segue subclass implementation).

When done, call dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: to "pop" the navigation controller.