# "unrecognized selector sent to instance" UINavigationController

Tags: xcode, setter

My Xcode app is getting the following exception error message.

```
-[UINavigationController setDeals:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8338d40
```

The exception is being thrown in the following context in the `prepareForSegue:` method, likely with the `destination` item. The key line where the exception is thrown is marked with this comment. `//**********exception`

BSViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class BSData;
@interface BSViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    }
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger iboard;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *deals;
@property (nonatomic, strong) BSData *data;
@end
```

BSViewController.m

```
#import "BSViewController.h"
#import "BSdealViewController.h"
#import "BSData.h"

@interface BSViewController ()
@end

@implementation BSViewController
@synthesize iboard, deals;

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // The identifier here must match the one you assigned to the segue in the storyboard.
    NSLog(@"identifier=%@ destination=%@", segue.identifier, segue.destinationViewController);
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"UrlToDeal"]) {
        BSData *data;
        BSdealViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
        data = [[BSData alloc] initWithNumber:self.iboard array:self.deals];
        NSLog(@"segue iboard:%d", self.iboard);
        NSLog(@"segue deals:%@", self.deals);
        destination.deals = self.deals;    //**********exception
        destination.iboard = self.iboard;
    }
}
@end
```

BSData.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BSData : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger iboard;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray * deals;
- (id)initWithNumber:(NSInteger)iboard array:(NSArray *)deals;

@end
```

BSData.m

```
#import "BSData.h"

@implementation BSData
- (id)initWithNumber:(NSInteger)iboard array:(NSArray *)deals
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"self initWithNumber");
        _iboard = iboard;
        _deals = deals;
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}
@end
```

BSdealViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>
#include "BSParam.h"
@class BSData;

@interface BSdealViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) BSData *data;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger iboard;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSArray *deals;

@end
```

BSdealViewController.m

```
#import "BSData.h"
#import "BSdealViewController.h"
#import "BSViewController.h"

@interface BSdealViewController ()
@end
```

Comment: The error message indicates that the destination of the seque is a UINavigationController, and not a BSdealViewController as you expect. You should check the destination controller in the storyboard file, perhaps you forgot to set the class to BSdealViewController.

Comment: Yes, there is a UINavigationController between the `BSViewController` and the `BSdealViewController` which I think is necessary b/c `BSdealViewController` contains a "Navigation item" (am I right that the "Navigation item" requires a UINavigationController?). And doesn't the segue have to go into the UINavigationController on its way to `BSdealViewController`? So how do I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: I am not a 100% "storyboard expert", but if the source controller (BSViewController) is already embedded in a navigation controller then you can segue directly to BSdealViewController. - Perhaps this describes a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812996/how-to-use-push-storyboard-segue-for-the-navigationcontroller.