# does a navigation bar get a Back Button

Tags: xcode, uistoryboard

The Xcode object library contains a UINavigation Bar that professes to enable both a Title and a Back button. "By default, UINavigationBar displays a back button on the left and a title in the center, but you can specify custom views for these, in addition to providing an optional button on the right of the navigation bar." With my **storyboard** and a UIView I see only the Title, no Back button in the simulator. Does the real device show both, or do I need to do some more hooking-up or segue-code to see the Back button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you used a master detail template then you can see the back button in detail view. if you have used it and there is no back button then it was a bug that prevented it for that particular project. trash that one and use a new one. if you add a navigation controller to an existing project when you ad the detailview the detailview will have a back button. i hope this answers your question.

EDIT:

that is correct my friend. if you do not use the navigation controller then you cant have that automatic back button, you can have it build programmatically.

Edit 1:

try the following. i put some notation in there to clarify the whole process.

```
//create the button
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

//specify the method attached to the button
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(goBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

//set the title for the button
 [button setTitle:@"My Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 //set the button frame
 button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40.0, 40.0);

 //add the button to my view
 [myView addSubview:button];
```

this is an old code that wrote sometime ago, but it should work just fine. the frame of the button is set to be on the left side but you can chage that if you need it. declare this in view did load method.

Comment: [I am trying to get around a problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427108/) by **not** using a navigation controller and using only a view controller. But you seem to be saying that if I do so, I cannot get the UINavigationBar to automatically have a Back button. Is that right?

Comment: Thanks for offering. I am sure I can use the help. [I found the following link on SO](http://osmorphis.blogspot.com/2009/05/multiple-buttons-on-navigation-bar.html) but it contains "..." in key places. I am assuming I will still do a good bit in the storyboard, but with a UIToolBar instead of a UINavigationBar. If you could help flesh it out, I would be very grateful.